# Modifying YAML's parsing of Truthies and Falsies

Tags: php, arrays, yaml

I am working with a form that when submitted the array gets run through the Spyc YAML library to dump a YAML file from the array. My issue being one of my fields may receive the input of "Y" and in testing this YAML converts y to 1 for true.

Looking further they actually convert any variation of "yes" to 1. Is there something I can do to spyc or before parsing down to YAML to keep the string value of Y?

Comment: Looking at the source, it lists an array of truthy values you could modify to remove `'y'`.  https://github.com/mustangostang/spyc/blob/master/Spyc.php#L407-L410  I have no other experience with this library to know if it is configurable at runtime though.

Comment: Thanks thats a great idea.
@MichaelBerkowski perfect it was in my library. Good looking out.

Answer (score 2):

YAML will only try to interpret **non-quoted** scalars in this way. E.g. scalars that are numbers only, become integers, as do scalars of the form 00:04:03 (this will become the integer 243). In a similar way non-quoted scalars that might be booleans are interpreted ( `Y`, `Yes`, `No`, etc. ).

To prevent this, just quote the scalars: `"Y"` is always a string in YAML.

The other thing you could do is look at a parser that conforms to the 1.2 specification. That a boolean value can be written as "Yes" is no longer in the YAML 1.2 spec (it was in 1.1), however most parsers will be backwards compatible even if the source is explicitly marked with a `%YAML 1.2` directive.